# Keyboard shortcut to select current line in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Is there any way to select the text of the current line in Xcode? This would be equivalent to `Cmd + l` in Sublime or `V` in vim.

Comment: `Cmd + l` it's already a shortcut in the newest Xcode version so you'll have to apply it to `Ctrl + cmd + l` or something.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually you can just use the normal Mac-Shortcuts.

**Beginning of Line**
<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd>

**Middle of Line**
1. <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> (this brings you to the end of the line)
2. <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> (selects everything to the left)

**End of Line**
<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>

Hope this helps :)

---

### Update

In Xcode 8, I have found the `Select Line` keyboard binding which you can set to <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> (that's `L`, not `i`) for instance to make Xcode select the line you're on right now when hitting that shortcut.

[image: key binding in xcode settings]

Comment: Is there any way to bind that into a simpler command like `Cmd + l`

Comment: Never mind, found it in System Preferences. Thanks for your help

Comment: I thought I found the right solution, but I wasn't able to. I suppose I'll stick to your solution :)

Comment: Hey, selecting until beginning selects the white space/tab space at the beginning of line as well. Is there any way I can select only till the beginning of content on the line, excluding the white space for indentation at the beginning?

Comment: Not that I know of..., @Cupidvogel

Comment: `cmd-l` is a shortcut already in use in the newest Xcode versions, so just apply it to `ctrl-cmd-l` or something - it works, though it's still not that useful like `ctrl-x` or `cmd-x` are in other IDEs

Answer (score 4):

You can actually assign a key command to this. In Xcode under Preferences > Key Bindings > Text search for "Select Line" and assign it to you preferred key command (I also prefer `command-l` to match Sublime Text)

[image]

Comment: Actually, it requires you to enter "line number, it isn't so useful. Maybe only useful if u have broken mouse or something :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKism.png

Comment: Are you sure you remapped that key? As I said in my response, I've assigned it to command-l, that isn't the default.

Comment: `cmd-l` is being used, so I've applied to `ctrl-cmd-l`, but it indeed works (though it's not useful like `ctrl-x` or `cmd-x` in other IDEs)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to select the line with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>.

(<kbd>a</kbd> selects from cursor till the beginning of the line, while <kbd>b</kbd> selects from the cursor till the end of the line).

It's a bit long shortcut but can be useful if you end up needing only part of the line or the whole.

You can also split this into 2 steps:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> to jump to the beginning of the line then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> to select till the end of the line.